# problema com uma função executar quando clicado enter

Tags: javascript

Boas, tenho a seguinte função javascript que está incluida numa query php e que é executada quando se dá um keyup num input como faço para executar só quando é clicada a tecla enter?

```js
 function insertchat". $row311['k'] ."(){
 var dzx='". $row311['k'] ."';  
 var kmn=$( '#txtContent". $row311['k'] ."' ).val();
 var lk='".$_SESSION['k'] ."';
if(kmn!=''){
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
  data: {dzx: dzx, kmn:kmn, lk:lk},
  url: 'insertchat4.php',
  
 
  success: function(datas2){
 if(datas2!==''){
   $('.m". $row311['k'] ."').append(datas2);
  
  
  }else{ $('.m". $row2['k'] ."').append('');}
 
  },
 error:function(datas2){
   
  },
  complete:function(datas2){
  
  }
 });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O `keyCode` 13 é para o [enter]

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {    
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        // código aqui    
    }    
});
```

Comment: vou tentar obrigado

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente obrigado